# Parallel multiline output in console

Tags: c#, concurrency, console, command-line-interface, multiline

I developed a CLI that loads different kinds of data in a database and outputs the status of each loading to the console.

```
class Program
{
    static ConsoleColor DefaultColor;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DefaultColor = Console.ForegroundColor;

        string[] names = { "order", "fidelity", "button", "user" };
        foreach(var n in names)
        {
            Refresh(n);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    static void Refresh(string name)
    {
        Console.Write($"Refresh {name,10} ... ");

        int random = new Random().Next();
        int delay = random % 1000 + 1000;
        Task.Delay(delay).Wait();
        if (random % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine($"OK ({delay,6} ms)");
            Console.ForegroundColor = DefaultColor;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("KO");
            Console.ForegroundColor = DefaultColor;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Each]

```
class Program
{
    static ConsoleColor DefaultColor;
    static void Main(string[] args) => MainTask(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    static async Task MainTask(string[] args)
    {
        DefaultColor = Console.ForegroundColor;

        string[] names = { "order", "fidelity", "button", "user" };
        await LoopAsync(names);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task LoopAsync(IEnumerable<string> thingsToLoop)
    {
        List<Task> listOfTasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (var thing in thingsToLoop)
        {
            listOfTasks.Add(Refresh(thing));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(listOfTasks);
    }

    static async Task Refresh(string name)
    {
        Console.Write($"Refresh {name,10} ... ");

        int random = new Random().Next();
        int delay = random % 1000 + 1000;
        await Task.Delay(delay);
        if (random % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.Write($"OK");
            Console.ForegroundColor = DefaultColor;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("KO");
            Console.ForegroundColor = DefaultColor;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($" ({delay,6} ms)");
    }
}
```

For the moment, it's done sequentially but I'd like to run each loading asynchronously. The problem is that results won't output to the corresponding line.

[image]

So I wonder how to output correctly concurrent tasks to a console.
I know it's possible as some CLI already do it (docker, node). I also want a spinner for pending loading. Do I need to set cursor at the beginning and rewrite everything?

Comment: Does -1 mean it's not possible?

Comment: You can set the cursor position to a specific location and just write in that place. Can you show a sample that illustrates what you've tried? Likely you can just pass a line number to each task and then it can set the position and write to the console.

Comment: The downvote button is typically used if someone doesn't think the question is useful, or if they think the author didn't do any research effort, or if they think the question is unclear. It would be nice if downvoters left a comment to indicate why they voted that way, but I suspect it's due to lack of any code.

Comment: @RufusL my code is just a loop on `Console.Write` / `Console.WriteLine`. I thought there were a way to reserve a line for each task. Moving cursor will twinkle display :/

Comment: You can use `Console.SetCursorPosition` to move the cursor to a specific location. If you set `Console.CursorVisible = false` there should be no flickering.

Comment: Here's a code sample that mimicks what I think you're looking for. There's a method that takes in a line number and a string description, and then it writes out a line as you have in your sample. It uses random numbers to determine how long each task will be and what the end result is (OK or KO). The main program then launches 4 tasks and waits for them to finish. Paste it into a new project and see if it helps...  [using tasks with console output](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SEfCYD)